# Laravel 8 authentication email translations

Tags: php, laravel, email, translation, breeze

I'm new to Laravel, I created a Laravel 8 / Breeze application and now I'm trying to translate the authentication emails. I don't want to customize these emails, just translate the text. Looking at the code below makes me think that there is a get() method somewhere that reads translations from a file. But I don't know where this file is read, and where it is (or should be) stored. I don't even know where the code is that reads the file ore defines it's location, or where I should put it. This code is in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Notifications/ResetPassword.php :

```
    /**
 * Get the reset password notification mail message for the given URL.
 *
 * @param  string  $url
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
protected function buildMailMessage($url)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(Lang::get('Reset Password Notification'))
        ->line(Lang::get('You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.'))
        ->action(Lang::get('Reset Password'), $url)
        ->line(Lang::get('This password reset link will expire in :count minutes.', ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')]))
        ->line(Lang::get('If you did not request a password reset, no further action is required.'));
}
```

Comment: you must read this doc: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization

Comment: Translations can be found in `resources/lang/{locale}` directory. Please read the [localization documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#defining-translation-strings) about this, as it provides more information.

Answer (score 4):

You might be tempted to put a "messages.php" file in /resources/lang/en/, but don't do it.  I've tried it and it doesn't work.

Instead, make a file called "en.json" and put it in /resources/lang/.  It might contain something like this:

```
{
    "Reset Password Notification": "This is your Password Link",
    "You are receiving this email because we received a password reset request for your account.": "You are receiving this because we sent it to you."
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. File path should be like that: `resources/lang/{locale}.json`.

Answer (score 0):

The translations should be found in `resources/lang/{locale}`
where locale is the target language
To learn more please read the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization